# MySQL Multiple Joins Causing Extreme Slowdown

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm attempting to get an export (into a table) of all images which are **NOT** used within our site.  I have the working code that does well on small data sets, but *still* hasn't returned results from our data set of over 4,000 images.  I have similar code to the following in my select statement:

```
SELECT a.id, a.image_name, a.last_modified, c1.val
    FROM a 
    /*file name could be used in table 'r' in the image1, image2, or image3 fields*/
    LEFT JOIN r ON a.image_name = r.image1 
        OR a.image_name = r.image2
        OR a.image_name = r.image3
    /*file name could be used anywhere within c.val field*/
    LEFT JOIN c c1 ON c1.val LIKE CONCAT('%', a.image_name,'%')
    /*get the page_id where the image name is found in c*/
    LEFT JOIN p p1 ON p1.page_id = c1.page_id   
    WHERE a.type = 'Image'  /*only images on this query*/
    AND r.image1 IS NULL /*no references in r.image1*/
    AND r.image2 IS NULL /*no references in r.image2*/
    AND r.image3 IS NULL /*no references in r.image3*/
    AND c1.val IS NULL /*no references in c.val OR...*/
    /*in the page where it was found, see if the page is a deleted page*/
    OR a.id NOT IN (SELECT a.id FROM a 
        LEFT JOIN c c2 ON c2.val LIKE CONCAT('%', a.image_name, '%')
        LEFT JOIN p p2 ON p2.page_id = c2.page_id
        WHERE p2.deleted IS NULL) /*deleted IS NULL means the page is not deleted*/
    ORDER BY a.last_modified DESC
```

There are really two scenarios when an image will show up in this export:

1. It's not found anywhere
2. It's found in a page which has been deleted

The first one is obtained by the outer SELECT minus the `OR a.id NOT IN...` part.  The second is obtained with the inner SELECT where I make sure the id is not included in the non-deleted pages.

I've tried changing the `OR a.id NOT IN...` to `OR p1.deleted IS NOT NULL` to take out the overhead of an inner SELECT, but that gives me all images which are found in deleted pages, not necessarily images which are ONLY found in deleted pages.

I've tried indexing the p.deleted, r.image1, r.image2, and r.image3 fields with no increase in efficiency. I've also tried making the BLOB field, c.val, a FULLTEXT index and that didn't help either.

a.id, a.image_name, c.page_id, and p.page_id are already indexed.

Again, this is working code, but I'm just trying to increase performance so we can put the code into production with our full data set.  Thank you in advanced for any responses.

Comment: The string joining all over the place, especially with leading wildcards, is going to mean poor performance whatever you do; but you might have some mild improvement if you eliminate the `OR`s by breaking this apart into 6 separate queries (`OR`s tend to make MySQL ignore indexes).

Comment: How would I concatenate the 6 separate queries together?  I'm using ADODB with $result = $db->execute($sql) @Uueerdo

Comment: You should be able to use `UNION`.

Comment: Also, I am not sure, but judging from the inline comments in the query, I am wondering if you might need to parenthesize your conditions to force order of evaluation. Is it intended to be `...AND (c1.val IS NULL OR...)` or `...AND c1.val IS NULL) OR (...`?

Comment: I feel like union would just combine the results instead of filtering the results of the first select, but I assume there has to be some way to format it differently to get the same results using a union.  And yes, my order of evaluation is correct, it's `...AND (c1.val IS NULL OR...)` @Uueerdo

Comment: UNION will combine results of all 6 selects, however, since I am suggesting you 'split them by OR conditions', the filtering is effectively the same; with UNION ALL you could see duplicate results you normally wouldn't (from records that satisfy more than one ORed condition), but UNION (without all) takes care of that. However, now that I think of it, it will effectively change the entire query into a `SELECT DISTINCT`; if that is an issue my suggestion cannot be used.

Comment: Also, you DO need to parenthesize. This query returns true `SELECT 1=0 AND 1=0 OR 1=1` indicating standard evaluation is `SELECT (1=0 AND 1=0) OR 1=1` _Maybe fixing that alone will help_

Comment: Oh, sorry, nevermind, I just noticed splitting out the OR's won't work in your case.

Comment: I don't think `SELECT DISTINCT` would be an issue here as I do want distinct rows from 'a'.  Could you provide an answer using the separate `SELECT`s with `UNION`s, including my `LEFT JOIN` grouping criteria?  That one seems mind boggling to me. Thanks in advance. @Uueerdo

Comment: Just saw your answer.  Let me check it out.  @Uueerdo

Comment: Just in case you were curious, a simple and very abbreviated example of what I meant by "splittng ORs" would be changing something like this `SELECT x FROM a LJ B ON a.id = b.a1 OR a.id = b.a2` to `SELECT x FROM a LJ B ON a.id = b.a1 UNION SELECT x FROM a LJ B ON a.id = b.a2`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the wild goose chase I started in the comments, I should have looked at the query closer; but this might help...

```
SELECT a.id, a.image_name, a.last_modified, c1.val
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN (
    /*file name could be used in table 'r' in the image1, image2, or image3 fields*/
    SELECT 1 AS matched, image1 AS image FROM r
    UNION SELECT 1, image2 FROM r
    UNION SELECT 1, image3 FROM r
) AS r2 ON a.image_name = r2.image
/*file name could be used anywhere within c.val field*/
LEFT JOIN c c1 ON c1.val LIKE CONCAT('%', a.image_name,'%')
/*get the page_id where the image name is found in c*/
LEFT JOIN p p1 ON p1.page_id = c1.page_id   
WHERE a.type = 'Image'  /*only images on this query*/
AND r2.matched IS NULL /*no references in r.image1, r.image2, or r.image3*/
AND (
    c1.val IS NULL /*no references in c.val OR...*/
    /*in the page where it was found, see if the page is a deleted page*/
    OR a.id NOT IN (
        SELECT a.id 
        FROM a 
            LEFT JOIN c c2 ON c2.val LIKE CONCAT('%', a.image_name, '%')
            LEFT JOIN p p2 ON p2.page_id = c2.page_id
        WHERE p2.deleted IS NULL
    ) /*deleted IS NULL means the page is not deleted*/
)
ORDER BY a.last_modified DESC
```

Comment: You fixed what you could, the OP should be aware that this part, LEFT JOIN c c1 ON c1.val LIKE CONCAT('%', a.image_name,'%'), is never going to be fast and it indicates a very poor database design indeed and that should be fixed rather than trying to performance tune something that can't be tuned due to bad design choices.

Comment: After a three test runs on a data set of about 500, your code increased my performance by about half a second from ~9.8 seconds to ~9.3 seconds.  I'm glad I'm making progress on it, but I know it's limited by the CONCAT I'm using.  I wish I would have designed the database, but that was done before I even got here. `c.val` is used as a "value" field for different editable fields within our Content Management System.  We use CKEditor with the c.val entry being full HTML that writes itself to the screen.  If an image is added into the src tag, I need to know, hence CONCAT %% @Uueerdo @HLGEM

Comment: I don't know about mysql but WHERE NOT EXISTS is often faster than NOT IN in SQL Server. Be worth a test. Alos could be worth pulling the data in C out to a temp table that meets the criteria and giving it the extra column that exactly matched the image_name part. (And index the temp table on the join field if mysql allows that)  So when you use it in your main query,(where it is referenced twice with that concatenate) you only have the already filtered values.

Comment: @GrayFoxStudios you might be able to get some more speed by merging the `c1` and `p1` references into a subquery, and merging the logic/need behind the `deleted` condtion in the WHERE subquery into that.

Comment: @HLGEM `[NOT] EXISTS` is usually faster in MySQL as well, but I am not sure how much it would help with a query that is not correlated; but as you and I just noticed, and I suggested in a less clear manner, extracting the `c & p` handling out of the main query, or merging it so it does not need processed twice, may show some improvements. (Edit: Actually, I don't think *NOT* EXISTS is actually that fast in MySQL; it still has to check every record, whereas with EXISTS it stops at first found.)